# Multiple irrational roots of irreducible polynomial over Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is it possible for irreducible polynomial $f \in Q[x]$ to have irrational multiple root?

I guess not, so I supposed to assume that my polynomial has factor $(x - a)^k$ in some extention, where $a$ is irrational, $k>1$ and come to contradiction, but I don't know what  could it be.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The field $\mathbb{Q}$ is a [perfect field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field): no irreducible polynomial over it has multiple roots.

To see it, recall that a polynomial $P$ has multiple roots if and only if it has a non-constant common factor with its formal derivative $P'$.  Now, since $P$ is irreducible, its only factors are itself and constant polynomials.  Since $P'$ has degree smaller than that of $P$, the only factors it can share with $P$ are constant polynomials.

Comment: Looks like it would be true even with $Q$ be replaced to any another field.  Does your solution use some properties of field $Q$?

Comment: @Vladislav  Yes: it would be true provided that the characteristic of the field did not divide the degree of the polynomial.  Otherwise, $P'$ would be zero, so $P$ would be a common factor of $P'$ and $P$.

Comment: I didn't get also the following: of course $P$ has no common factors with any $P'$ of smaller degree being considered as element of $Q[x]$, but how about extentions? Irrational roots appear in extention of $Q[x]$, so our polynomial is not irreducible anymore and arguments don't work.  Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Vladislav  The reason is the following: by Bézout's theorem, $P$ and $P'$ are coprime iff there are polynomials $A,B\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $AP + BP' = 1$.  Now let $K$ be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.  The polynomials $A,B$ can be viewed in $K[X]$, and we still have that $AP+BP'=1$.  So $P$ and $P'$ are still coprime over $K$.

Answer (score -2):

No, let $G$ be the Galois group of $Q[X]/P$, $(X-a)^k$ divides $P$ implies that  $(\Pi_{g\in G}(X-g(a)))^k$ divides $P$ which implies that $P$ is not irreducible if $k>1$ since $\Pi_{g\in G}(X-g(a))\in Q[X]$.

Comment: the characteristic of $Q$ is zero. thus extensions are separable

Comment: really, it is about the fact that the characteristic of $Q$ is zero, it is not like that I read it anyway ?

Comment: you may rephrase it as you like,  but it is about multiple roots, anyway, the conclusion of a theorem is always the hypothesis which are rephrased

Comment: I never used this fact, I said that $\Pi_{g\in G}(X-g(a))\in Q[X]$ which is not the same thing.

Comment: think about it, it is a basic fact in Galois theory.